# Selenium fails with page crash after adding login/passwd to simple script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, webdriver, screen-scraping

I am using Python but I am not familiar with Selenium.

My heat pump producer has a login page where I can see a lot of technical details about my heat pump, and I want to fetch these using a script which logs in automatically, fetches them all and stores into a DB or whatever.

The URL is https://remotecontrol.at/
But even before clicking the login button with Selenium, the script fails everytime with the error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash"

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I didn't find a solution online. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

my_username = "my_user_name"
my_password = "my_secret_passwd"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://remotecontrol.at/")

username = driver.find_element("id", "login")
username.send_keys(my_username)

passwd = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
passwd.send_keys(my_password)

#login_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login")
#login_button.click()

# close the driver
driver.close()
```

And the Output is every time the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Haus\Heliotherm\website_login.py", line 17, in <module>
    passwd.send_keys(my_password)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Programs\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.200)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009172A3+45731]
    (No symbol) [0x008A2D51]
    (No symbol) [0x007986D0]
    (No symbol) [0x0078AA11]
    (No symbol) [0x007897F2]
    (No symbol) [0x00789FFA]
    (No symbol) [0x00793882]
    (No symbol) [0x007A0D68]
    (No symbol) [0x007FB657]
    (No symbol) [0x007E7DD6]
    (No symbol) [0x007C31F6]
    (No symbol) [0x007C439D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C20716+3229462]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C684C8+3523784]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C6214C+3498316]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009A1680+611968]
    (No symbol) [0x008ACCCC]
    (No symbol) [0x008A8DF8]
    (No symbol) [0x008A8F1D]
    (No symbol) [0x0089B2C7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7640FCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C97C6E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77C97C3E+238]
```

I tried adding options (no-sandbox) but nothing changed.

Comment: I always put sleep statements in while loading a webpage with Selenium, to give the page time to render. Maybe try that.

Comment: I don't have any issues with your code if I use just `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` .